# Use Blend SDK Event triggers to fire a button click with relevant list view item MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, wpf-controls

I'm trying to use the event trigger from Blend to fire a button click event of a listview item, it should work so that the item **does not** have to be selected for the relevant row to be referenced.

My code is...

```
Public void MyCommand(object obj)
{
    // the tag of this has the search type
    ListViewItem item = obj as ListViewItem;

    // do my dreary domain work...
}
```

my xaml is...

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SystemSetupItems}" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding Selected, Mode=TwoWay}" 
    MinHeight="120" >
    <ListView.View>
    <GridView>
        <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
        <GridViewColumn Header="Description" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Description}" />
        <GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button  >
                        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseClick">
                                <i:InvokeCommandAction CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListViewItem, AncestorLevel=1}}" Command="{Binding MyCommand}"/>
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                         </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                     </Button>
                 </DataTemplate>
             </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn>                        
    </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

but this doesn't work at all, alternatively I can do this in my xaml button definition

```
<GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Button Command="{Binding OpenWorkSpaceCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=Name}" Content="Edit..." DataContext="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListView}}"  >                                 
        </Button>
    </DataTemplate>
</GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
```

but this required the listview item to be previously selected, which is not the behaviour I want.

Answer (score 0):

For my DataGrid I have a button on each item using the cell template. Each item is an object of type `Meal`. In my Meal.cs file I have an event definition like so:

```
public Meal()
{
    RemoveMealCommand = new RelayCommand(() => RemoveMealCommandExecute());
}

public RelayCommand RemoveMealCommand
{
    get;
    set;
}

public delegate void RemoveMealEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
public event RemoveMealEventHandler RemoveMealEvent;

private void RemoveMealCommandExecute()
{
    RemoveMealEvent(this, null);
}
```

In my viewmodel for every meal in my list I can just add a handler to that event. And for my xaml button I just set the command to the Meal's RelayCommand.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Command="{Binding Path=RemoveMealCommand}">
                <Image Width="13" Height="13" Source="/Images/delete-icon.png"/>
            </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Now when you click the button the Meal is responsible for firing the event and the viewmodel is responsible for handling it.

Comment: I try this and get a 'Delegate 'System.Action<object>' does not take 0 arguments' compile error

Comment: What line is the error you are getting? My guess is the event handler in your ViewModel?

Comment: oops, it's on this line 

RemoveMealCommand = new RelayCommand(() => RemoveMealCommandExecute());

Comment: the entire code is...
CheeseFactoryCommand = new RelayCommand(() => CheeseFactoryExecute());
public RelayCommand CheeseFactoryCommand { get; set; }
public delegate void CheeseFactoryEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
public event CheeseFactoryEventHandler CheeseFactoryEvent;
private void CheeseFactoryExecute(object sender)
{
    CheeseFactoryEvent(this, null);
    }

Comment: I am using the MVVMLight library for my RelayCommands. Your Library may have a different implementation. The code I posted was an example that works for me. I was hoping you could used it to figure out how to attach an event to each of your `SystemSetupItems`. I don't think copying my code into yours will help.

Comment: ok, I wonder why is wasn't working myself, i'm using a different template. Thanks for posting.